# SMTP Error (451): Failed to add recipient. Temporary lookup failure

Tags: postfix, smtp

- Installed **iRedMail** on Debian Server
- Can Login to **Roundcube**

Sending Mails from Roundcube results in the following error:

> **SMTP Error (451): Failed to add recipient "XXX@mydomain.de". Temporary lookup failure.**

**/var/log/mail.err**

```
mydomain roundcube: SMTP Error: SMTP error: Failed to add recipient 'XXX@mydomain.de' in /usr/share/apache2/roundcubemail-1.0.4/program/lib/Roundcube/rcube.php on line 1505 (POST /mail/?_task=mail&_unlock=loading1425838552649&_lang=de_DE&_framed=1?_task=mail&_action=send)
```

**/var/log/mail.info**

```
postfix/cleanup[26223]: warning: proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql/sender_bcc_maps_user.cf lookup error for "root@mydomain.de"
postfix/cleanup[26223]: warning: B8B82101DF6: sender_bcc_maps lookup problem
postfix/pickup[25858]: warning: maildrop/82D57FFE93: error writing B8B82101DF6: queue file write error
postfix/pickup[25858]: warning: B8E3C101DF6: message has been queued for 2 days
postfix/pickup[25858]: B8E3C101DF6: uid=0 from=<root>
```

**postconf -n**

```
alias_database = hash:/etc/postfix/aliases
alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/aliases
allow_min_user = no
allow_percent_hack = no
append_dot_mydomain = no
biff = no
bounce_queue_lifetime = 4h
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
command_directory = /usr/sbin
config_directory = /etc/postfix
content_filter = smtp-amavis:[127.0.0.1]:10024
daemon_directory = /usr/lib/postfix
data_directory = /var/lib/postfix
debugger_command = PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin ddd $daemon_directory/$process_name $process_id & sleep 5
delay_warning_time = 0h
disable_vrfy_command = yes
dovecot_destination_recipient_limit = 1
enable_original_recipient = no
home_mailbox = Maildir/
html_directory = no
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all
lmtp_tls_mandatory_protocols = !SSLv2 !SSLv3
lmtp_tls_protocols = !SSLv2 !SSLv3
local_transport = local
mailbox_command = /usr/lib/dovecot/deliver
mailbox_size_limit = 51200000
mailq_path = /usr/bin/mailq
manpage_directory = /usr/share/man
maximal_backoff_time = 4000s
maximal_queue_lifetime = 4h
message_size_limit = 15728640
minimal_backoff_time = 300s
mydestination = $myhostname, localhost, localhost.localdomain, localhost.$myhostname
mydomain = mydomain.de
myhostname = mydomain.de
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8
mynetworks_style = host
myorigin = mydomain.de
newaliases_path = /usr/bin/newaliases
proxy_read_maps = $canonical_maps $lmtp_generic_maps $local_recipient_maps $mydestination $mynetworks $recipient_bcc_maps $recipient_canonical_maps $relay_domains $relay_recipient_maps $relocated_maps $sender_bcc_maps $sender_canonical_maps $smtp_generic_maps $smtpd_sender_login_maps $transport_maps $virtual_alias_domains $virtual_alias_maps $virtual_mailbox_domains $virtual_mailbox_maps $smtpd_sender_restrictions
queue_run_delay = 300s
readme_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix
recipient_bcc_maps = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql/recipient_bcc_maps_user.cf, proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql/recipient_bcc_maps_domain.cf
recipient_delimiter = +
relay_domains = $mydestination, proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql/relay_domains.cf
sample_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix
sender_bcc_maps = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql/sender_bcc_maps_user.cf, proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql/sender_bcc_maps_domain.cf
sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail
setgid_group = postdrop
smtp-amavis_destination_recipient_limit = 1
smtp_data_init_timeout = 240s
smtp_data_xfer_timeout = 600s
smtp_tls_CAfile = $smtpd_tls_CAfile
smtp_tls_loglevel = 0
smtp_tls_mandatory_protocols = !SSLv2 !SSLv3
smtp_tls_note_starttls_offer = yes
smtp_tls_protocols = !SSLv2 !SSLv3
smtp_tls_security_level = may
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Debian/GNU)
smtpd_client_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated, reject_unknown_client_hostname
smtpd_data_restrictions = reject_unauth_pipelining
smtpd_end_of_data_restrictions = check_policy_service inet:127.0.0.1:7777, check_policy_service inet:127.0.0.1:10031,
smtpd_helo_required = yes
smtpd_helo_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated, reject_non_fqdn_helo_hostname, reject_invalid_helo_hostname, check_helo_access pcre:/etc/postfix/helo_access.pcre
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = reject_unknown_sender_domain, reject_unknown_recipient_domain, reject_non_fqdn_sender, reject_non_fqdn_recipient, reject_unlisted_recipient, check_policy_service inet:127.0.0.1:7777, check_policy_service inet:127.0.0.1:10031, permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated, reject_unauth_destination
smtpd_reject_unlisted_recipient = yes
smtpd_reject_unlisted_sender = yes
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_local_domain =
smtpd_sasl_path = private/dovecot-auth
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_sender_login_maps = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql/sender_login_maps.cf
smtpd_sender_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, reject_sender_login_mismatch, permit_sasl_authenticated
smtpd_tls_CAfile = /etc/ssl/certs/iRedMail.crt
smtpd_tls_auth_only = yes
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/ssl/certs/iRedMail.crt
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/ssl/private/iRedMail.key
smtpd_tls_loglevel = 0
smtpd_tls_mandatory_protocols = !SSLv2 !SSLv3
smtpd_tls_protocols = !SSLv2 !SSLv3
smtpd_tls_security_level = may
swap_bangpath = no
tls_random_source = dev:/dev/urandom
transport_maps = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql/transport_maps_user.cf, proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql/transport_maps_domain.cf
unknown_local_recipient_reject_code = 550
virtual_alias_domains =
virtual_alias_maps = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql/virtual_alias_maps.cf, proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql/domain_alias_maps.cf, proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql/catchall_maps.cf, proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql/domain_alias_catchall_maps.cf
virtual_gid_maps = static:2000
virtual_mailbox_base = /var/vmail
virtual_mailbox_domains = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql/virtual_mailbox_domains.cf
virtual_mailbox_limit = 51200000
virtual_mailbox_maps = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql/virtual_mailbox_maps.cf
virtual_minimum_uid = 2000
virtual_transport = dovecot
virtual_uid_maps = static:2000
```

Comment: That has something to do with your Postfix configuration, check its logs.

Comment: I posted the logentry in my question. are there any other logs specific to postifx?

Comment: Any other log in var/log/mail.log?

Comment: I edited my question with additional warnings in mail.log @masegaloeh

Comment: Did you have any other error on **proxymap** section like [this question](http://serverfault.com/questions/624679/postfix-intermittent-lookup-failures)? Try to run `grep proxymap /var/log/mail*` and post the output here. :)

Answer (score 1):

In `/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_email2email.cf` there is a row:

```
SELECT email FROM users WHERE email='%s'
```

Solution: replace  'email' with  'username', because there is no email fieldname in the table.

Answer (score 0):

Im not too sure about Roundcube as I still use Squirrelmail, but I know having the proxy: in front of mysql: can cause issues with the virtual look up called in php. This may not be THE answer but its something to try.

Roundcube does require direct mysql access to add both the sender and the recipient addresses to the SQL database. these are verified by the postfix/dovecot look up mechanism. Try ensuring that roundcube has the required permissions and that the roundcube password (not your user password) is correct. Mysql uses MD5-sum to encrypt passwords so you may have to change the password to ensure it is correct. I use phpmyadmin to do this and is/was part of the iRedmail package in Debian. this can be accessed by http://ip-to-your-server/phpmyadmin